# How to mark a Model Request member as Required on Swagger Doc using NET Core

Tags: .net-core, swagger

I'm trying to replace some code on my endpoint with a lot of query values to start using a model.
After the change, my endpoint looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Obtener Articulos paginados con filtrado
    /// </summary> 
    /// <remarks>Origen de datos datos de Vista</remarks>            
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(ArticulosPagina))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetArticulos([FromQuery] ArticulosRequestModel ArticulosRequest, [FromQuery] PaginadoRequestModel PaginadoRequest)
    {
        var filters = mapper.Map<ArticulosViewParametros>(ArticulosRequest);
        var paginador = mapper.Map<PaginadoParametros>(PaginadoRequest);

        var articulos = await service.GetArticulos(filters, paginador);

        return new ObjectResult(articulos);
    }
```

And my model looks like this:

```
 public class ArticulosRequestModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Filter is required.")]
    [FromQuery(Name = "filtro")]
    public string Filtro { get; set; }

    [FromQuery(Name = "activos")]
    public int Activos { get; set; }
}
```

Doing so and adding the [Required] attribute it supposed that my endpoint should request the "Filtro" parameter as required. Instead I See this:

[image]

I supposed i'm missing something, but don't know what. Thanks!

Comment: Try add `[Required]` to the `ArticulosRequest` parameter as well?

Comment: Yes, I already try this, but then every member in ArticulosRequestModel is marked as required